# Consumer cannot connect to amqp || Celery

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery, consumer

In production server, I am getting the following error in celery console which never happened before. I found the same issue in other posts, they are saying give valid url but the url i have given in settings.py is very much valid.

Also Rabbitmq is active.

```
[2020-05-13 16:47:01,945: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://admin:**@site_name:5672//: timed out.
Trying again in 16.00 seconds...
```

Please suggest a workaround as i am stuck with it from very long time.

I have also tried celery several times

Comment: Are you sure that credentials in your url are the same for your production environment?

Comment: Yes 100% sure, the credentials are perfect.....

Answer (score 1):

The issue is now resolved.

Turned out that the url name resolution **site_name** is not getting connected in the server. i changed it to localhost and its working fine now.

Thanks